# main function in haskell instead of ghci

Tags: haskell

hi i'm new in using haskell.

i'm actually using ghci to compile this code:

```
module Expr where

import Control.Applicative
import System.Environment

data Expr = Add Expr Expr
          | Sub Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          | Lit Integer

eval :: Expr -> Integer
eval e = case e of
  Add a b -> eval a + eval b
  Sub a b -> eval a - eval b
  Mul a b -> eval a * eval b
  Lit n   -> n

-- Nouveau datatype nécessaire pour les instances
data Parser r = Parser {parse :: String -> Maybe (r, String)}

-- Instances
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> case p s of
    Just (a, s') -> Just (f a, s')
    Nothing      -> Nothing

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x = Parser $ \s -> Just (x, s)
  Parser p1 <*> pp2 = Parser $ \s -> case p1 s of
    Just (f, s') -> case parse pp2 s' of
      Just (a, s'') -> Just (f a, s'')
      Nothing       -> Nothing
    Nothing -> Nothing

instance Alternative Parser where
  empty = Parser $ const Nothing
  (Parser p1) <|> pp2 = Parser $ \s -> p1 s <|> parse pp2 s

-- Le reste est identique
runParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParser (Parser p) s = case p s of
  Just (r, "") -> Just r
  _            -> Nothing

check :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
check f = Parser $ \s -> case s of
  (x:xs) | f x -> Just (x, xs)
  _            -> Nothing

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = check (== c)

oneOf :: [Char] -> Parser Char
oneOf cs = check (\c -> elem c cs)

number :: Parser Integer
number = read <$> some digit
  where digit = oneOf "0123456789"

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = add_sub
  where
    add_sub = binOp Add '+' mul <|> binOp Sub '-' mul <|> mul
    mul = binOp Mul '*' factor <|> factor
    factor = parens <|> lit
    lit = Lit <$> number
    parens = char '(' *> expr <* char ')'
    binOp c o p = c <$> p <*> (char o *> p)

evalExpr :: String -> Maybe Integer
evalExpr s = (fmap eval) $ runParser expr $ concat $ words s
```

what i'm trying to do is to create a Main to compile and run this code by myself and i'm struggling to do so.

so far i manage to understand and i would like to have something that is structurated like this:

```
module Main where

import System.Environment
import Expr

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [] ->  putStrLn "No argument"
    [s]->  evalExpr args
```

i want to know if i can use ghci to generate a main or if there is another solution to create one

Comment: What do you mean exactly by ‘generating a main’? I’m not sure I understand what you’re trying to say here.

Comment: what i mean is i can run my code whitout a main thnks to ghci but i don't want to run a prompt,i want to compile the code mysefl so it would look like: ./Expr 1 + 1          but since i'm not really good in haskell i cant seem to make a correct main that compile and work, my actual main form above makes two error of comilation.

Comment: What commands are you using for compilation? If you’re using Stack (as you said in another comment), then you should be able to build your project simply by running `stack build`. This will then generate an executable which you should be able to run using `stack exec <your-project-name>`; if you want to copy that executable into your working directory, run `stack install --local-bin-path .`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you've created a project using `cabal` or `stack`, then your `Expr` module should be in `src/Expr.hs` and your `Main` module should be in `src/Main.hs` or `app/Main.hs`. The code you have looks at first glance like it should compile and run fine.

You can then either run a REPL instance (`cabal repl` or `stack repl`) in your project directory and call the `main` function from there or you can run it as an executable (`cabal run` or `stack run`) and pass in your arguments from the command-line.

If you haven't created a project using either of the tools I mentioned above, then this documentation should prove useful:

- [Cabal documentation](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html)
- [Stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/)

Edit:

I had neglected to look at the code in detail before/try to compile & run it.

Your main function has some issues with the pattern match line of:

```
    [s] -> evalExpr args
```

Since your `evalExpr` function takes a `String` you need to pass it something instead of `args`, which is of type `[String]`.

Also, the result of `evalExpr` is of type `Maybe Integer` and needs to be of type `IO ()` to end the case statement properly.

If you replace it with this:

```
    _ ->  putStrLn . show $ evalExpr (unwords args)
```

then running `stack run 1 + 1` from the command-line will output `Just 2`.

To get this to run as a stand-alone executable, you'll have to run `stack install` which will create an executable on your system that you can run. On mine it outputs to `~/.local/bin/Expr-exe` which I can then call:

```
paul@Pauls-MacBook-Pro Expr % ~/.local/bin/Expr-exe 1 + 1
Just 2
```

(side note: `stack install` is apparently a short-cut for `stack build --copy-bins`)

Comment: you assume correclty i have used stack to create my project. but i don't want to use ghci to compile and run my code. i have made a makefile that create an executable but like i said my main is not correct and make errors in compilation, when i used ghci to try it i didn't had to create a main so that's why i created the one above in app/Main.hs so when i compile it using a Makefile it can make me an executable so i can try it like this: ./Expr 1 + 1

Comment: @Krokm I updated my answer; sorry I hadn't looked deeper into this the first time around

Answer (score 0):

You already know that you need to create a constant called `main` whose type is `IO ()`.

Let's start at your compilation errors. These are coming up because you have indented the contents of you `main` action less than the `do` keyword. Because Haskell is whitespace-sensitive, this is confusing the compiler. So your example above should actually look like this:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do args <- getArgs
          case args of []  ->  putStrLn "No argument"
                       [s] ->  evalExpr args
```

I can't tell you whether this is actually what you want in your `main` action because I don't know what you want it to do, but it will probably look similar to what you're running in GHCi.

For example, if your GHCi session looks like this:

```hs
 Prelude> let x = foo bar
 Prelude> print x
```

the equivalent `main` would look like this:

```hs
 main :: IO ()
 main = do let x = foo bar
           print x
```